# Delphi - Custom thread not being created

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, delphi, tthread, tpersistent

i'm having a bit of a problem here. I have a custom class that inherits TPersistent class, inside(private section) this custom class, i have a custom made TThread with overriden Execute method which fires every (1000 ms). Everything works great, until i move my 2 custom classes to a new Unit...

```
type
  TMyThread= class(TThread)
  protected
   procedure Execute; override;
  end;

  TMyClass = class(TPersistent)
  private
   T: TMyThread;
  protected
   constructor Create;
  public
   destructor Destroy; override;
  end;


implementation

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
 while not Self.Terminated do begin
  Sleep(1000);
  MessageBox(0, 'test', nil, MB_OK)
 end;
end;

constructor TMyClass.Create;
begin
 inherited Create;
 t := TMyThread.Create(False);
end;

destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
begin
 t.Terminate;
 t.WaitFor;
 FreeAndNil(t);
 inherited Destroy;
end;
```

The above code works great in the main project unit, but when i move it to a new unit, the thread code no longer works, i get an AV, when i try to free a TMyClass object. I think the thread is not being constructed at all, and that's why i get an AV when i try to free it... but why? it shouldn't matter in which Unit the code is...

Unit1:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  p: TMyClass;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 p.Free; //Getting an AV
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 p := TMyClass.Create;
end;

end.
```

Unit2:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  protected
   procedure Execute; override;
  end;

  TMyClass = class(TPersistent)
  private
   T: TMyThread;
  protected
   constructor Create;
  public
   destructor Destroy; override;
  end;


implementation

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
 while not Self.Terminated do begin
  Sleep(1000);
  MessageBox(0, 'test', nil, MB_OK)
 end;
end;

constructor TMyClass.Create;
begin
 inherited Create;
 t := TMyThread.Create(False);
end;

destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
begin
 t.Terminate;
 t.WaitFor;
 FreeAndNil(t);
 inherited Destroy;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Why are you displaying a MessageBox in a thread?

Comment: It was for testing purpose only, nothing more, wanted to save some time. To test, if the thread fired.

Comment: If you use the debugger, you will notice that no code is generated for the `TMyClass.Create` constructor. (No blue dots). This will give you a good hint what is going on.

Comment: Now i noticed, i should use the debugger more often, Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor `TMyClass.Create` is declared protected. That means it is not visible from another unit. Hence `TMyClass.Create` is not executed and instead you are calling `TObject.Create`. In turn that means that the thread is never created and you encounter a runtime error when the destructor runs because `T` is `nil`.

Declare the constructor with `public` visibility.

Comment: It worked, silly me... i'm kinda new to OOP, i should read some extra info on those Protected, Public, Published sections
Thank you soo much, have a good day kind sir!